# Poetry: how to deal with hardware dependant libraries

Tags: pytorch, python-poetry

I'm trying to configure my poetry `pyproject.toml` in a way that we can choose between a cpu and a gpu version of the dependencies. The reason for that is that the library `torch` needs to be installed by specifying the hardware you want to use (see poetry's [Instructions for installing PyTorch](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6409)). My final goal is to be able to install the dependencies on my local computer (Mac with M1 ship) as well as to be able to generate a wheel to send to some distant server and then pip install it (I'm actually using [Databricks dbx](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html) to do that). Here is the configuration file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my_project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Me"]
readme = "README.md"

packages = [
    {include = "my_project"},
    {include = "scripts"}
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.8.10"
torch = [
    {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.12.1-cp38-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl", markers="extra == 'cpu'"},
    {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch-1.12.1%2Bcu102-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl", markers="extra == 'gpu'"}
]

[tool.poetry.extras]
cpu=["torch"]
gpu=["torch"]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I run:

```
poetry install --extras="cpu"
```

I get the following error:

```
Because my_project depends on both torch (1.12.1) @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.12.1-cp38-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl and torch (1.12.1+cu102) @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch-1.12.1%2Bcu102-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl, version solving failed.
```

Comment: As far as I know... -- It is up to the user installing the project (application or library) to do the work of deciding between CPU and GPU variants. As the author/maintainer of the project there is not much you can do to influence this, apart from writing clear documentation. -- The direct URLs that you write in the Poetry sections of `pyproject.toml` will only be usable by the co-maintainers of that project. Once the project is built into wheels and uploaded to PyPI, this info will be lost.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I didn't know that the URLs were lost when building the wheel, that's good to know. It means that I should only declare the versions in the toml file, but I should prevent poetry from installing them when using `poetry install` command (cause it will fail) ? How could I do that ?

Comment: If I remember correctly but I might be wrong, it is possible to build wheels containing the direct URLs (with Poetry and other tools), but PyPI will reject those wheels. -- How will your project be consumed? Who will install it? Is it an application or a library? Do you want to publish it to PyPI or only distribute via a private internal index server maybe?

Comment: I would like to build the wheel, send it to a private distant server, then run `pip install my_wheel`on this distant server then run `python entry_point`.

Comment: Then since it is private, I guess it is okay for this project to have direct URLs in its dependency metadata. -- I see [you reached out to Poetry and got some feedback](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6409#issuecomment-1310173723). -- My personal point of view is that it seems the packaging of `torch` is at fault. If I recall correctly your use case comes up regularly, and a couple of times I dug deeper, but it always turned out to be a dead end, blocked by `torch`'s packaging process.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your feedback ! Just to summarize, your overall point of view is that the major problem that needs to be solved here is that torch does not provide a single entry point to install it ? So we might need to way several years before dealing with gpu/cuda etc. is easy enough to provide the install with a single `pip install torch` on whatever hardware ?

Comment: My point of view on PyTorch packaging (but I am not up-to-date so take with a grain of salt) is that it should be distributed on PyPI under multiple variants `torch-cpu`, `torch-cu102`, etc. with added possibility to install as `torch[cpu]`, `torch[cu102]`, etc. -- Anyway it is all hypothetical and does not help you solve your use case today. -- My recommendation is to not overthink it, but document it clearly that it is up to the final installer to decide which version of `torch` to install and how. It can not be fully automated via the package metadata.

Comment: Got it, I think it makes sense